# Which option is correct? and why

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect

If we .... all day, we might have finished the paper on time.

1/ worked

2/ had worked

3/ have worked

4/ would have worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we **had worked** all day, we might have finished the paper on time.

This sentence shows the ***probability*** that the work would have been completed if they all had worked on time.

***Had*** represents a work started in the past which already got finished in the past. According to this sentence, the time limit has exhausted hence the task timing has been finished.

The other cases are not true because:

- "worked" being the simple past tense doesn't actually indicate the distinctive time period.
- "would have (something)" always depends on a condition that happened first, whose consequence is denoted by *would have* sentences.
- "have worked" is just not acceptable because it is in the present tense, and the rest of the sentence is already in the past.

Answer (score 1):

1, 2 and 3 are all grammatical, but they have different meanings.

The most natural is the past perfect **had worked**, which implies a counterfactual: “we” did not work all day, and the paper was not finished on time.

The simple past tense **worked** has a similar meaning, but unlike the perfect tense, this sentence would be correct even if the deadline is still in the future. That is, some portion of the day has passed, and “we” did not work, so there is no longer any chance that “we” could finish the paper on time.

The present perfect **have worked** would be used to express a conditional in the present: it is now the end of the day, and if “we” have worked all day, then the paper may now be done, but the speaker is unaware of whether either part of that is true. You may see this more often with the qualifier “just”, to indicate the possibility is remote:

> If we have worked all day, we **just** might have finished in time.

—--

The start of your last suggestion, “**If we would have**” is quite common in informal English, but is considered by many to be ungrammatical. It’s best to avoid it.